Websocket 401 Unauthorized Cloudfront
I'm trying to replicate a websocket connection. In HTML code with JavaScript, the connection happens perfectly. However, using the same headers in python with websockets or websocket-client I receive the following error:
Handshake status 401 Unauthorized

{'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'content-length': '0', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Sun, 16 Jun 2024 22:56:20 GMT', 'x-cache': ' Error from cloudfront'}

Why does it happen? What do I stop sending?

Try to check you request header with websocket.enableTrace(True) if there are any duplicities.
Link to the doc https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#debug-and-logging-options
We have had same problem with websocket-client. CloudFront returned 401 when the header was invalid.
